# Why is there no outline in 3d View when I select an object?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, selection-tools

If I select an object, the outline does not show up in 3d View. I mean there is no highlight around the object so that you can recognize what's actually selected. How can i fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the *Filter Menu* and enable *Selectable* in the *Restriction Toggles* list:

[image]

See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#filter

Answer (score 2):

You can try either turning on [Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html), or change the viewport setting. It's located on the top right of the [3D View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/index.html). If you’ve turned on the overlay, then try clicking the triangle button on the right:

[image]